# "Present Modally" does not show when another modal is already presented

Tags: ios, swift

In my iOS application, my VC is presenting a modal (A) via code.

However, when I already have another modal presented (B), this one is not showing at all.

However, when (A) is deinitted, I see that (B) also gets deinitted.

How can I make sure that (B) always gets shown, no matter what, and in front of all other modals?

```
performSegueWithIdentifier(SEGUES.SegueTabBarToBroadcast, sender: view )
```

My TabBarViewController is calling this segue. (The segue is modal according to storyboard).

The problem occurs when one of the view controllers in my TabBar presents a modal.  Then, when I try to call `performSegueWithIdentifier`, the modal doesn't show (but yet deinits when I close the other modal).

I just want this modal to present NO MATTER WHAT. This modal should overlap all other modals.

I also tried this, but the problem persists:

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let bvc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BroadcastViewController") as! BroadcastViewController
        self.presentViewController( bvc , animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: The point is How are you presenting the Modal, using `[self.navigationController present]` or `[self present];`? Can you show some code?

Comment: Please add the code that you are using (For this particular issue a sample app will be good)

Comment: you can present modals over modals as long as you declare a new navigationcontoller and present the new navigation controller with a view controller over the currently presented modal view controller

Comment: yes definatly, otherwise you have to dismiss presented View Controller

Comment: One problem also, or a solution, is why don't you root you rUITabBarController in a UINavigationController, and then call to your UITabBArController to present the modal in your viewcontrollers that are in the tabs of the UITabBarController, this is the way I do this and have done this, it makes more sense since you want to present over the entire stack of controllers, that is self.tabBarController.navigationController presentViewController

Comment: and another thing, when you start like this: self.tabBarController.navigationController presentViewController and present another naivagioncontroller with a viewcontroller, you should present the NEXT viewcontroller from this combo from the navigationController that you just made in the new Presented view controller, so you have to call back to back nearest navigation controller to present another navigaiton/view controlller combo

Comment: Instead of doing `performSegueWithIdentifier`, can you call `UIViewController *controller=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFER"];` and `[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: @iphonic, I've tried that as well. The problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

Presenting multiple view controllers as a modal is not good practice. If you want to present your vc no matter what, then you have to understand the hierarchy of your view controllers. Shortly, you can present view controller modally on the vc with view that has a window, and when you have already presented any vc modally, your view controller's view that has presented the vc does not have the window, thus can't present other view controller modally. Conclusion: you can present vc modally from the top-most vc. So, solution would be keeping reference to the top-most vc, and presenting the desired vc from that vc. Another solution would be adding vc's view directly to the main window of the app, but I would not recommend solving your problem that way. Hope, this helps.